# Parse string in swift

Tags: string, swift

I have a huge text in `String`.

For example `"... value=word. ..."`. How can I get the `string "word"` if I know that before I have `"value="` and after `"."`?

for example:

```
for str in string {
    if str == "value=" {
        // then get the strings until .
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `String` with a kind of `sliceBetween` method:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
  func sliceFrom(start: String, to: String) -> String? {
    guard let s = rangeOfString(start)?.endIndex else { return nil }
    guard let e = rangeOfString(to, range: s..<endIndex)?.startIndex else { return nil }
    return self[s..<e]
  }
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
"... value=word. ...".sliceFrom("value=", to: ". ") // "word"
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSRegularExpression` should solve your issue.

In order to use it, you will need to understand [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) first. In your case, you can use `value=[\\w]+[^.]+` as your regex pattern.

The following code will give you a `[String]` object contains `value=allCharacterBeforeFirstPeriod`

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "value=[\\w]+[^.]+", options: [])
let nsStr = str as NSString
let array = regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsStr.length))
let results = array.map({ nsStr.substringWithRange($0.range) })
```

And then if you only need the value after `value=`, you can use another `map` function to do it:

`results.map({ $0.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("value=", withString: "") })`

I have tested the code with a 10,000 characters `String`. It finishes in ~0.3 sec

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way to do this would be to use NSRegularExpression. [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Given an input `String` like this

```
let text = "key0=value0&key1=value1&key2=value2"
```

You can organireduce method

```
let dict = text.characters.split("&").reduce([String:String]()) { (var result, keyValue) -> [String:String] in
        let chunks = keyValue.split("=")
        guard let first = chunks.first, last = chunks.last else { return result }
        let key = String(first)
        let value = String(last)
        result[key] = value
        return result
}
```

Now everything is stored inside `dict` and you can easily access it

```
dict["key2"] // "value2"
```